# Function Based Index based on a column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table with a column IS_LOGGED which takes only two values 'Y' or 'N'

I want to have a Function based index on the column IS_LOGGED where value is 'Y'.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your requirement?

Comment: good job with rewriting the exam question...

Comment: How about you read the oracle documentation to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of index is to list all entries in an easy and fast to access manner.
Suppose you get a 1500 pages thick book to read with an index listing only specific chapters. What is the use of such an index?
I don't think you need a function based index here. Simply create an index and modify your queries to include IS_LOGGED = 'Y' clause.